# How to open file in C program?

Tags: c, file, io

The code here is a code from a website. Since I was facing an issue with my origin code, I ended up trying this implementation from a website. But turns out I have the same issue with this program too

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int num;
   FILE *fptr;

   if ((fptr = fopen("D:\\TestFile\\test.txt","r")) == NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file\n");
        perror(fptr);
       // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
       exit(1);
   }

   fscanf(fptr,"%d", &num);

   printf("Value of n=%d\n", num);
   printf("%s\n", fptr);
   fclose(fptr); 
  
   return 0;
}
```

I am stuck with the if condition i.e., whatever I do I am not able to read the file except the root directory. Even though I specify the path, it still looks for the file under root directory.

I am not sure why it's not working, provided the same code works fine in Linux

Comment: *it still looks for the file under root directory*. How do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: The parameter to `perror` is a string to print, not a `FILE *`.

Comment: What is the error? You seem to have some error-checking (though you're missing it for `fscanf`, which really needs it, and as dbush notes, it's partly wrong), what is it reporting? "Doesn't work" isn't helpful; a proper [MCVE] tells us *how* it behaves instead.

Comment: C is a very unforgiving language that expects a lot from the programmer. Here you're taking `fptr`, which you've asserted to be `NULL`, and jamming it into `perror()` as if that might extract some magical information from that pointer. Please, [read the documentation on functions like `perror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) before sticking something in the arguments. **Verify you're calling functions correctly** as the compiler is not obligated to point out your mistakes, it'll just do what it assumes you meant, often incorrectly.

Comment: Are you trying to read from a path relative to your current program folder as opposed to an absolute path? In that case, start the file path from your current folder instead of the D drive. Also, as others have mentioned, `perror` takes a string, not a file pointer

Comment: Don't call `perror()` after calling `printf()`, as the latter may change the value of `errno`.

Comment: Hi @kaylum, sorry I didn't mention but when I change the mode from "read" to "write". It create the file in the working directory with the filename same as pathname and now if I change mode to read, then the code works fine

Comment: Hi @ShadowRanger, I used `perror("Error: ")` for error checking after change and it returned "No such file or directory"

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for putting your effort and time in helping out. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 mistakes, the one related to `perror` mentioned in the comments, and the last `printf`. Now if the program is still not working, it could be interesting to check the error or to get the program output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int num;
   FILE *fptr;

   if ((fptr = fopen("D:\\TestFile\\test.txt","r")) == NULL){
       // printf("Error! opening file\n");
       // perror(fptr);  // MISTAKE-1: perror parameter is a string
       perror("Error! opening file");
       // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
       exit(1);
   }

   fscanf(fptr,"%d", &num);

   printf("Value of n=%d\n", num);
   //printf("%s\n", fptr);             // MISTAKE-2: fptr is not a string
   fclose(fptr); 
  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, for the perror I realized that mistake later after working on it a while. And thank you for your effort and time, it works!

I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

the posted code does not cleanly compile!

Here is the results of compiling with many of the warnings enabled:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o" 

untitled1.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled1.c:11:16: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘perror’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   11 |         perror(fptr);
      |                ^~~~
      |                |
      |                FILE * {aka struct _IO_FILE *}
      
In file included from untitled1.c:1:

/usr/include/stdio.h:775:33: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘FILE *’ {aka ‘struct _IO_FILE *’}
  775 | extern void perror (const char *__s);
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
      
untitled1.c:19:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘FILE *’ {aka ‘struct _IO_FILE *’} [-Wformat=]
   19 |    printf("%s\n", fptr);
      |            ~^     ~~~~
      |             |     |
      |             |     FILE * {aka struct _IO_FILE *}
      |             char *
      
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Note; the statement: *Compilation finished successfully.*  just means the compiler applied some work around to each of the problems.  It does NOT mean the correct code was produced.